# How to locate a specific tag with multiple classes in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

I'm, trying to make a simple bot for twitter to send a message to someone direct.
But my problem is I don't know how can I find some elements with multiple classes.
For example, I'm trying to find this part of the web page :

```
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">@SomeUser</span>
```

and to doing this is used this code in python:

```
mes = bot.find_element_by_css_selector("span.css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")
```

or this :

```
mes = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='span.css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0']")
```

but I get this message :

```
Unable to locate element: span.css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0
```

where am I wrong?
why it can't find it?
I tried to find more tutorials and references but there are just some simple examples and I do not learn enough from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted use CSS Selector with multiple classes:

```
span.css-901oao.css-16my406.r-1qd0xha.r-ad9z0x.r-bcqeeo.r-qvutc0
```

In CSS selector you have to seperate each class with `.(dot)`

If you wanted use Xpath with multiple classes:

```
//span[@class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"]
```